# Tumblr Android App : How to make it accesible for non-Tumblr Users

Tags: android, tumblr

I'm Creating an android app for a particular Tumblr page. My problem is how do i make it usable for non-Tumblr Users since they cant authorize (oAuth) and therefore no Token nor Token Secret. Please is this possible at all and if so how do i Implement . 
Note : I'm using the Jumblr Api

Help is Needed  (In any form)

Comment: is it a private tumblr page ?

Comment: most of the tumblr api method do not require an authenticated user

Comment: So do u mean i do not necessarily need a token or token secret ?

Comment: if you look at the tumblr api (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) there are methods that require no authentication whatsoever, some that require your api_key (meaning you need to register your app), and some that require an oauth user.